# OrderBy a Many To Many relationship with Entity Sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, sql-order-by

I'm trying to better utilize the resources of the *Entity Sql* in the following scenario: I have a table `Book` which has a Many-To-Many relationship with the `Author` table. Each book may have from 0 to N authors. I would like to sort the books by the first author name, ie the first record found in this relationship (or *null* when no authors are linked to a book).

With T-SQL it can be done without difficulty:

```
SELECT
    b.*
FROM
    Book AS b
    JOIN BookAuthor AS ba ON b.BookId = ba.BookId
    JOIN Author AS a ON ba.AuthorId = a.AuthorId
ORDER BY
    a.AuthorName;
```

But I cannot think of how to adapt my code bellow to achieve it. Indeed I don't know how to write something equivalent directly with *Entity Sql* too.

```
Entities e = new Entities();
var books = e.Books;
var query = books.Include("Authors");

if (sorting == null)
    query = query.OrderBy("it.Title asc");
else
    query = query.OrderBy("it.Authors.Name asc"); // This isn't it.

return query.Skip(paging.Skip).Take(paging.Take).ToList();
```

Could someone explain me how to modify my code to generate the Entity Sql for the desired result? Or even explain me how to write by hand a query using `CreateQuery<Book>()` to achieve it?

**EDIT**

Just to elucidate, I'll be working with a very large collection of books (around 100k). Sorting them in memory would be very impactful on the performance. I wish the answers would focus on how to generate the desired ordering using Entity Sql, *so the orderby will happens on the database*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OrderBy method expects you to give it a lambda expression (well, actually a `Func` delegate, but most people would use lambdas to make them) that can be run to select the field to sort by. Also, OrderBy always orders ascending; if you want descending order there is an `OrderByDescending` method.

```
var query = books
  .Include("Authors")
  .OrderBy(book => book.Authors.Any()
    ? book.Authors.FirstOrDefault().Name
    : string.Empty);
```

This is basically telling the OrderBy method: "for each book in the sequence, if there are any  authors, select the first one's name as my sort key; otherwise, select the empty string. Then return me the books sorted by the sort key."

You could put anything in place of the `string.Empty`, including for example `book.Title` or any other property of the book to use in place of the last name for sorting.

EDIT from comments:

As long as the sorting behavior you ask for isn't too complex, the Entity Framework's query provider can usually figure out how to turn it into SQL. It will try really, really hard to do that, and if it can't you'll get a query error. The only time the sorting would be done in client-side objects is if you forced the query to run (e.g. `.AsEnumerable()`) before the `OrderBy` was called.

In this case, the EF outputs a select statement that includes the following calculated field:

```
    CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[BookAuthor] AS [Extent4]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent4].[Books_Id]
    )) THEN [Limit1].[Name] ELSE @p__linq__0 END AS [C1],
```

Then orders by that.

`@p__linq__0` is a parameter, passed in as `string.Empty`, so you can see it converted the lambda expression into SQL pretty directly. Extent and Limit are just aliases used in the generated SQL for the joined tables etc. `Extent1` is `[Books]` and `Limit1` is:

```
SELECT TOP (1) -- Field list goes here.
FROM  [dbo].[BookAuthor] AS [Extent2]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Authors] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent2].[Authors_Id]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Books_Id]
```

Comment: But with your code the sort happens after the SQL execution, ie with LINQ To Objects sorting, right? Is there any way to force the sort to be executed by the database?

Comment: (Sorry, meant to get back to this yesterday.) Actually, in this case, no. As long as the sort criteria is not *too* complex, the EF provider can usually turn it into SQL syntax. I'll update my answer to show you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care where the sorting is happening (i.e. SQL vs In Code), you can retrieve your result set, and sort it using your own sorting code after the query results have been returned.  In my experience, getting specialized sorting like this to work with Entity Framework can be very difficult, frustrating and time consuming.

Comment: In fact, I think that SQL sorting is better, since its faster (I'll be working with about 100k books). Or am I wrong?

Comment: With large result sets, SQL sorting is ideal.  Michael posted an approach I was unfamiliar with and it should work for you...the generated SQL should sort the result set the way you want.